# Java Swing read only unique lines from file into JtextArea

Tags: java, swing, bufferedreader, filereader, jtextarea

Hello I am developing a swing application that reads contents from the text file and adds them to the `JTextArea`.
I am able to read the file contents using the `textarea.read()` method

But the problem is the text file contains many duplicates which are unnecessary and need to be discarded.

Here is the code for reading:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("D:/abc.txt")));          
jTextArea1.read(reader, "D:/abc.txt");

}
```

I've seen people suggesting the usage of `LinkedHashSet`, but I don't know how to use it in this context.

I need a solution that can read only unique lines from the text file and put it into the `jTextArea`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I need a solution that can read only unique lines from the text file and put it into the jTextArea.* - I think that the better solution is to read all the lines of the input file, not only those which are unique. It will be easier to do. You could create a while loop that reads each line of the input file, assign this line to the String variable and add this line to the `LinkedHashSet<String> yourSet` declared outside of this loop. You can add these lines (Strings) to `yourSet` with the method `yourSet.add(String yourString)`. After that you could iterate over your set and send each String line to `yourJTextArea`:

```
for(String s : yourSet) {
    yourJTextArea.append(s + "\n" );
}
```

Comment: Ok, let me know if all works fine, because I wrote it without the access to the compiler to check if this all would work fine enough, but it should be rather ok.

Comment: Works perfectly but content is added to jTextArea as a continuous stream without line break. How do you suggest the inclusion of line breaks as well?   Here is what I did :                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("D:/abc.txt")));    
             String readLine = "";
             LinkedHashSet<String> lh = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
             while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) { 
              lh.add(readLine);
            }
              for(String s : lh) {
              jTextArea1.append(s);
                    }

Comment: Nevermind adding jTextArea1.append(s + "\n"); did the trick . Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @NyteFyre If my answer helped you, you might consider upvoting my answer and checking it on the left side as an accepted answer. Wish you all the best!

Answer (score 0):

You should read the file line by line using .readLine() and add the line to a HashSet Object, sets only allow unique elements.
Once you have read the entire file and added them to the set you can just add the String to the textarea

Answer (score 0):

Set is really good solution. In this context read file from new line in.nextLine() store value in String str = new String(value) and then set.add(str)
After fill you textArea with values from Set